# How many different items needed for haar cascade classifier

Tags: classification, cascade

When creating a haar cascade classifier, can I use pictures of only 1 item or is it necessary to use pictures of many items of the same class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should work even with only one item but keep in mind that more than one item means more performance and accuracy.